# Is it possible for me to choose to show or hide bottom navigation bar when I move to new page with navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

everyone.
I'm making an app which has bottom navigation bar with two items, and each item has buttons to move new pages.
Let's say each of those item is called for A and B.
A has a button for moving to new Page C. C shows today's weather.  And I want to see bottom navigation bar in C as well.
B also has a button for moving to new Page D. D is login page. And I don't want to see bottom navigation bar in D.

I tried to use IndexedStack and GlobalKey, and it did work for showing bottom navigation bar in C. But I failed to hide bottom navigation bar with it in D.

I also read many articles here and there but never worked.
Can anybody help me?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentTab;
  List<Widget> _tabList = [
    FirstTab(),
    SecondTab()
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentTab = 0;
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabList[_currentTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            title: Text('Weather')
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('Login')
          )
        ],
        onTap: onItemTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WeatherPage()));
          },
          child: Text('To see the weather today'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
          },
          child: Text('To Login'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WeatherPage extends StatelessWidget { // This page needs bottom navigation bar
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Rainy'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget { // There is no bottom navigation bar on this page
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Click to login'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** 
Have a new bottomNavbar in the WeatherPage (first solution in comment section):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackOverflow2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverflow2State createState() => _StackOverflow2State();
}

class _StackOverflow2State extends State<StackOverflow2> {
  int _currentTab;
  List<Widget> _tabList = [FirstTab(), SecondTab()];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentTab = 0;
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabList[_currentTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text('Weather')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Login'))
        ],
        onTap: onItemTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // Th
  @override
  _WeatherPageState createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  int _currentTab;
  Widget myCenter = Center(
      child: Text('Rainy'),
    );
  List<Widget> _tabList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabList = [myCenter, SecondTab()];
    _currentTab = 0;

  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabList[_currentTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text('Weather')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Login'))
        ],
        onTap: onItemTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WeatherPage()));
          },
          child: Text('To see the weather today'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
          },
          child: Text('To Login'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // There is no bottom navigation bar on this page
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Click to login'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm a beginner not only in flutter, but also in english as you see. I attached some code. You can go to the weather page on weather tab, and the login page on login tab. Now, neither the weather page nor the login page has bottom navigation bar. But I hope the weather page has same bottom navigation bar

Comment: first solution: You can manually add the Navigation bar to the WeatherPage, like you did on the home page. Second Solution: instead of going (pushing) to the other pages, On the home page, you can change the scaffold's body when the button is tapped. You can have a bool or int variable to control this. Edited the answer.

Comment: @JinsubKim is this what u wanted? let me know. I'm curious :).

Comment: I'm really sorry about being late. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much! You're awesome! I'd thought that there is no ways but reusing the bottom navigation bar whom I used in HomePage. But there is another way making new bottom navigation bar as you did. Thank you! It's really helpful.